# Client side authentication/read/write to firebase database viability?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase

I am new to Web app development using firebase,
I am using NodeJs. I have used the Javascript API's provided by firebase for Google SignIn authentication and also accessing real-time database read and write.

The code that I have written for authentication is on the client js files - which is visible in the browser if I look at the page source. For example, I have used '/admin' as a route at client js if user.uid of logged in user matches with admin's uid.. (I am not sure how to protect /admin page..)

Should I not use the Javascript client api's of firebase as it seems to blur security ?

I came to know about Cloud functions which I can use in nodejs server to authenticate, read/write to the database so that keeping my server as in-charge and giving data to the client whenever requested?

Comment: And [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482366/is-it-safe-to-expose-firebase-apikey-to-the-public) you should look at.

Comment: Thanks for finding these duplicates @AndréKool!

Comment: @Frank. good to see ur post, i saw ur firebase vid, thanks for shutting me, a googler knows better